# Changing notes position based on new bpm

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, math, audio

I have a `.mboy` json file that are build with bpm 128 which is the audio original bpm.

have a look below at the file.

```js
 export default {
"editor": "mboy-editor-2.1.1",
"format_version": "2.0",
"audio": {
    "artist": "test",
    "title": "NO COPYRIGHT SHORT MUSIC (SOLO RECORD)",
    "album": "",
    "subgenre": "",
    "date": "",
    "download_link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Atv-zwhSyFE",
    "comments": "",
    "genre": "Other"
},
"author": "<zx<zx",
"date": "2022-11-17",
"tempo": 128,
"start_pos": 0,
"tracks": [{
    "instrument": "bass",
    "name": "",
    "color": "ff009fff",
    "bars": [{
        "index": 0,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 800,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 1,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1000,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 2,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 900,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 3,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 1000,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 4,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 5,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 900,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 6,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 300,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 7,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 900,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 8,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 700,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1300,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 9,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 700,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1300,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 10,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 700,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 11,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 900,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 12,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 0,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 13,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 0,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 14,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 800,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 15,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1000,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 16,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": []
    }, {
        "index": 17,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": ["ToLeft"]
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 18,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": []
    }, {
        "index": 19,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": []
    }, {
        "index": 20,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": []
    }
    ]
}, {
    "instrument": "drums",
    "name": "",
    "color": "ff009fff",
    "bars": [{
        "index": 0,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 800,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 1,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 800,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1300,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 2,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 900,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 3,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1000,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1300,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 4,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 600,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1000,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 5,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 6,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 700,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 900,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 7,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 600,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 800,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1000,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1300,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 8,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 600,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 900,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1300,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 9,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 10,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 0,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 900,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1000,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1300,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 11,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 500,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 800,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }, {
        "index": 12,
        "quarters_count": 4,
        "notes": [{
            "pos": 200,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 400,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }, {
            "pos": 1100,
            "len": 100,
            "markers": []
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
],
"markers": [{
    "id": "extended",
    "code": "*",
    "color": "ffffff00"
}, {
    "id": "ToLeft",
    "code": "<",
    "color": "ffffff00"
}, {
    "id": "ToRight",
    "code": ">",
    "color": "ffffff00"
}
]
}
```

my game play just fine with the current file, but what I want is to make it slower and that mean I have to change the bpm from 128 to 240.

I have the current `pos` and `len` for the bpm 128.

I want to know if I can change the position of the notes based on the new bpm.

I do not want to change the audio file only the notes above so it can follow the new speed and still use the same audio file.

### Update about mboy editor.

`mboy editor` is a free application for making charts for rythm games, here is the link https://vfpe.itch.io/mboy-editor. the `pos` is a position of the note in the chart where each `bar` represent 0 to 1500 in length, in it there is `x` `notes`. the next bar represent p+n where n is the next bar `notes` and p is the previous length of the notes.

This below is the equation I came up with to write calculate the right pos of the notes

```
   const getYPosition = (mboyNote: any, bar: any, trackIndex: number) => {
            const q = bar.index * (bar.quarters_count * windowPropeties.noteHeight)
            let appender = (bar.index * 15 * (windowPropeties.noteHeight));
            let y = windowPropeties.height - (appender + mboyNote.pos + q);

            return y;
        }
```

Comment: What is an .mboy file? What produces it? Are the len and pos values within it absolute or relative? What units do they represent? Milliseconds?  Google shows nothing.

Comment: I did not specify that, good that you asked, I update the Q and wrote about this under update. please read it.

Comment: Thx. It would also be helpful to start your question by describing exactly what you intend your app to do for the user (what they see and do) and how you are making it work

Comment: If you a answer my questions Ill work with you.  A picture/video is worth a thousand words.  Can you record a video that shows the game “just working fine” and also shows you “change the bpm”?

Comment: @NerdyBunz I am new to the game world. And really not that good with maths so I am learning. I am developing this with react-native so you can imagine how hard this really is. The games source is public and you can download it if you want https://github.com/AlenToma/MelodyTappar